# Find and replace <p> with return key entry in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have just implemented `nl2br(htmlspecialchars(...` to display user entered MySQL data. Annoyingly various posts are littered with

tags from before I knew about `nl2br`. Is there a quick way to scan through MySQL (I use php myAdmin) and replace `<p>` with a return key entry that nl2br picks up on? There are only

tags in one of the columns. Thanks

EDIT: an example

```
...d the wood on the front car is cracked - it has stood the test of time very well. 
<p>
For such an ancient coaster, it affords a surprisingly good ride – this relic can still deliver..
```

so the `<p>` should be removed and replaced with just the empty line

Comment: Do you have an example of an entry and what you want replaced?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO made an edit with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, the `<p>` elements are not necessary. They can just be [replaced](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) with `\n`:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET theColumn = REPLACE(theColumn, '<p>', '\n')
```